# Create a one line data frame with NAs for a list of column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list with names and I would like to create a data frame with these names as column names and one NA value. I will replace some of the NAs during a loop.

```
n <- c('a','b')
d <- data.frame(a=NA, b=NA)
```

So basically I have a vector like `n` and I would like to automatically create a NA-data frame like `d`. Is there a handy way of doing so?

Comment: Perhaps `setDT(setNames(as.list(rep(NA, length(n))),n))[]` or `data.frame(setNames(as.list(rep(NA, length(n))),n))`

Comment: Or a more compact option is `data.frame(split(rep(NA,length(n)), n))` or `setDT(split(rep(NA,length(n)), n))[]` for creating data.table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways you do this.  Here are two -

```
setNames(do.call(data.frame, rep(list(NA), length(n))), n)
#    a  b
# 1 NA NA
```

which is basically generalized for any `n`

```
N <- letters[1:6]
setNames(do.call(data.frame, rep(list(NA), length(N))), N)
#    a  b  c  d  e  f
# 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

A second method uses `as.data.frame()`

```
as.data.frame(setNames(rep(list(NA), length(N)), N))
#    a  b  c  d  e  f
# 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Or, since your just using NA values, `NA[seq_along(N)]` can replace `rep()`

```
setNames(data.frame(as.list(NA[seq_along(N)])), N)
#    a  b  c  d  e  f
# 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Note that all these will produce logical classed columns.  For other classes, you can use `NA_integer_`, `NA_character_`, etc.